# All possible combinations of columns with sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I want to generate Report having multiple group conditions and need to display all the possible combination of my table with sum of any one column

here is my table structure

```
Company Budget  Account Benificiary Objevctive  Spare1  Spare2  Amount
C1        B1     A1       BA1          OB1         0     0       200
C1        B2     A1       BA2          OB2         0     0       300
C2        B1     A2       BA2          OB2        S1     S1      400
C1        B1     A1       BA1          OB1         0     0       400
```

Here is the required output which is having all the possible combinations of 7 columns and sum in last column based on the combinations

```
Company Budget  Account Benificiary Objevctive  Spare1   Spare2     Amount
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB1       0       0     600
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB1       0       S1    0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB1       S1       0    0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB1       S1      S1    0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB2       0       0     0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB2       0       S1    0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB2       S1      0     0
    C1        B1      A1       BA1           OB2       S1      S1    0
    C1        B1      A1       BA2           OB1       0       0     0
```

im not able to generate query which will give above output

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer may depend on the dbms used.)

Comment: @jarlh its MS SQL Server

Comment: *all the possible combinations of 7 columns* means you need to `CROSS JOIN` seven `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table` queries and then `LEFT JOIN` to it.

Comment: @dnoeth ill try this

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth..i was confused on what is meant by all possible combinations

Comment: The output data you give doesn't quite seem to match your input data and the description of the task. The second row of the input data contains the combination "Company = C1, Budget = B2, Beneficiary = BA2", etc. As this combination is contained in the input data, it's clearly a "possible" combination. But it's not contained in the output data, which has "Budget = B1" for each row. Maybe you're only showing some of the output rows? In this case, you should at least specify how you selected them.

Comment: And how is the sum determined? Grouped by what columns? If all of them, why is there no 300 or 400 values?

Comment: @Parfait it will come i had just given the example all the combinations will come

Comment: Can you answer @MightyCurious's question? Your desired output is not all possible combinations. For instance, there is no `S1` corresponding to rows of `OB1`. Hence, three rows are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Able to achieve the above output using below Query

```
SELECT B.BENEFICIARY,
       B.BUDGETHOLDER,
       B.CITY,
       B.FIELDNAME,
       B.OBJECTIVE,
       SUM(B.value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.BENEFICIARY,
                    A.BUDGETHOLDER,
                    A.CITY,
                    A.FIELDNAME,
                    A.OBJECTIVE,
                    A.value
    FROM (
        SELECT t.BENEFICIARY,
               t.BUDGETHOLDER,
               t.CITY,
               t.FIELDNAME,
               t.OBJECTIVE,
               t.value value
        FROM #temp T, #temp TT
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN #temp T1 ON A.BENEFICIARY = t1.BENEFICIARY
        AND A.BUDGETHOLDER = t1.BUDGETHOLDER
        AND A.CITY = t1.CITY
        AND A.OBJECTIVE = t1.OBJECTIVE
) B
GROUP BY B.BENEFICIARY,
         B.BUDGETHOLDER,
         B.CITY,
         B.OBJECTIVE,
         B.FIELDNAME
```